# How to extract xml child element

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to figure out the code to extract xml child (I think this is worded correctly) elements. I have searched and tried many samples but cannot find how to drill down to pick out the section I want and return the information I need. Maybe I all I need is someone to define the data I am trying to pull so I can read up on the issue, of course any code would be very helpful and I will figure it out from there. Thanks in advanced for any help!

Here is the xml file. I am trying to run an if statement to find the section named `<STATISTICTYPE>PVCAP_CharactersSaved</STATISTICTYPE>` and return the `<JOBNAME>`,`<TIMEDELTA>`,`<VALUESUM>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PVCAPTURESTATISTICCONTAINTER xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PVCAPTUREJOBSTATISTICS>
    <PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY>
      <STATISTICTYPE>PVCAP_CharactersSaved</STATISTICTYPE>
      <STATISTICNAME>Characters saved</STATISTICNAME>
      <JOBID>24</JOBID>
      <JOBNAME>HEAT FILES</JOBNAME>
      <TIMEDELTA>422</TIMEDELTA>
      <VALUESUM>25432</VALUESUM>
    </PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY>
    <PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY>
      <STATISTICTYPE>PVCAP_CharactersSaved_NoMM</STATISTICTYPE>
      <STATISTICNAME>Characters saved (no match and merge)</STATISTICNAME>
      <JOBID>24</JOBID>
      <JOBNAME>HEAT FILES</JOBNAME>
      <TIMEDELTA>422</TIMEDELTA>
      <VALUESUM>25432</VALUESUM>
    </PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY>
    </PVCAPTUREJOBSTATISTICS>
      <DOCUMENTCOUNT>762</DOCUMENTCOUNT>
      <PAGECOUNT>3194</PAGECOUNT>  
      <IMAGECOUNT>3194</IMAGECOUNT>  
      <VERSION>2.0</VERSION>
</PVCAPTURESTATISTICCONTAINTER>
```

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't given us any of the code you've tried. I'd strongly suggest using LINQ to XML - it makes this *really* simple.

Comment: Either use LINQ to XML or [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) with xpath selection... What did you try so far? (Post the (snippet) of code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML, particularly the [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
var element = XElement.Parse(xmlStr).Element("PVCAPTUREJOBSTATISTICS")
                                    .Elements("PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY")
                                    .First(c => c.Element("STATISTICTYPE").Value == "PVCAP_CharactersSaved")

var jobName = element.Element("JOBNAME").Value;
var timeDelta = element.Element("TIMEDELTA").Value;
var valueSum = element.Element("VALUESUM").Value;
```

You'll want to add in some error handling and whatnot here, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
XElement res = XElement.Parse(xmlResult);
foreach(var elem in res.Element("PVCAPTUREJOBSTATISTICS").Elements("PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY"))
{
    if (elem.Element("STATISTICTYPE").Value.Equals("PVCAP_CharactersSaved", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        string jobName = elem.Element("JOBNAME").Value;
        string timeDelta = elem.Element("TIMEDELTA").Value;
        string valueSum = elem.Element("VALUESUM").Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and LINQ-to-XML to do that quite easily, for example :

```
string xml = "your xml content here";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//or if you have the xml file instead :
//XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants("PVCAPTURESTATISTICSUMMARY")
                .Where(o => (string) o.Element("STATISTICTYPE") == "PVCAP_CharactersSaved")
                .Select(o => new
                                 {
                                     jobname = (string) o.Element("JOBNAME"),
                                     timedelta = (string) o.Element("TIMEDELTA"),
                                     valuesum = (string) o.Element("VALUESUM")
                                 });
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: You guys Rock! I did not expect to recive a working model to get me started down the right path but to my suprise you all banged it right out. Now i can see the different ways to achive the same resaults but more impotantly i think i now understand that what i was trying to work with and retrive is called an "element" not a node, attribute, or child element. Now i can go do my homework and get a full umderstanding. Thanks again i have been beating my head on the keyboard for days now.